# Run JMC tool rools programmatically

Tags: java, jfr, jmc

My goal is to write Java class that will analyze jfr dump and give warnings like JMC tool like in attached screenshot. For example: "There are long socket read pauses" or "The JVM was paused for 100 % during ..." etc.

I saw an example of org.openjdk.jmc.flightrecorder.rules.RuleRegistry. However it contains no rules.
How can I export all rules that **JMC tool** runs on JFR dump and load them into my RuleRegistry?

```
        IItemCollection events = JfrLoaderToolkit.loadEvents(new File("abcd.jfr"));
        for (IRule rule : RuleRegistry.getRules())
        {
            RunnableFuture<Result> future = rule.evaluate(events, IPreferenceValueProvider.DEFAULT_VALUES); 
future.run(); 
            Result result = future.get();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just ensure that you have all the proper bundles on the classpath.

See https://github.com/thegreystone/jmc-jshell for an example.

Comment: Thanks Hirt. It worked. But the result summary is like that: "There are long socket read pauses in this recording (the longest is {longestReadTime}) etc." Where can I get the values for {longestReadTime} and other variables?

Comment: Hm. The result summary should include the actual values.